# Не работает подсветка кода в ответах и вопросах

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

**Выдержка из FAQ:**

1. [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)
2. [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

**Пример вопроса с неработающей подстветкой:**
[Header('Location: index.php'); не работает как исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412811/headerlocation-index-php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

**Вставленный код:**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    function call() {
        var msg = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: msg,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, str) {
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
    }
```